# How to display Image on a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, firemonkey

I've made a small Form App using the DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python, but I'm not sure how to add or display an `Image` onto the `Form`. Here's my current code:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 800
        self.Height = 500

        self.imgPlay = Image(self)
        self.imgPlay.Parent = self
        self.imgPlay.Position.X = 100
        self.imgPlay.Position.Y = 100
        self.imgPlay.Width = 300
        self.imgPlay.Height = 300

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

I've tried:

```
self.imgPlay.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('play.png')
```

but the error is `TypeError: "LoadFromFile" called with invalid arguments.`

I've also tried:

```
self.imgPlay.Picture.LoadFromFile('play.png')
```

The error is then `AttributeError: Error in getting property "Picture". Error: Unknown attribute`

And lastly, I've tried simply saying:

```
self.imgPlay.LoadFromFile('play.png')
```

With a similar error `AttributeError: Error in getting property "LoadFromFile". Error: Unknown attribute`

What is the correct way to load an image file into the Image Component? How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.imgPlay.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('play.png')` is the correct way to load an image into the component. I suspect the given file path ('play.png') doesn't exist. Something you can maybe do is get the path of the current file and then load it from that folder:

```
import os

...

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
self.imgPlay.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path + '\play.png')
```

Using this code works on my side:
[image: Minecraft Dirt Image showing on Python GUI App]

I'm successfully showing an `Image` on the `Form`.

---

Alternatively to the `Image` component, there is also an `ImageControl` component that works similarly. Here's a code sample and screenshot using an `ImageControl` instead of `Image`:

```
self.imgDirt = ImageControl(self)
self.imgDirt.Parent = self
self.imgDirt.Position.X = 100
self.imgDirt.Position.Y = 100
self.imgDirt.Width = 400
self.imgDirt.Height = 400

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
self.imgDirt.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path + '\dirt.png')
```

[image: Python GUI App with Minecraft Dirt block image]